# Sharepoint Search Administrative status : Unable to connect to the remote server

Tags: enterprise-search, sharepoint-search

I am receiving the following message in the Search Administration dashboard

> " Unable to connect to the remote server. "

[image: Error]

When clicking on Content Sources, I get the following error message :

> "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it [ip address]:[port]"

Answer (score 0):

It was solved after I restarted the system. The cause of the issue was unknown.